Set language scope for autocomplete in VS Code
Where in Settings do I go to specify which languages apply each set of autocomplete rules? Right now, HTML files have a set of autocomplete rules, and I would like PHP files to follow the same rules.

VS Code doesn't have built-in support for all different languages.
You can install VS Code extensions for languages you want.
For example, there is an extension for PHP that has IntelliSense feature: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode
